# Telerik RadGrid export to word doesn't call its RenderMethodDelegate

Tags: c#, gridview, telerik, export, radgrid

I've got a Telerik.RadGrid and on a button click I'm calling `Grid.MasterTableView.ExportToWord();`.

I've attached the debugger and found that inside the Telerik sources, in the `TableViewExporter`, the `ExportToWord()` method adds a render delegate to the page using `SetRenderMethodDelegate`.

I set a break point in the method added, `WordExportRenderPage`, but it never gets hit.

Should not the method be called when the Grid is rendered? How can I make sure it is?

I'm pulling my hair out here....